# Synergy doesn't work correctly if I switch client/server role (left of works, right of does not)

Tags: windows-7, macos, synergy

When I use my win7/64bit as a server, with the mac (10.7.5) on its left, it works.

Screens:
[Mac/10.7.5]---[Win7/64bit]

I've now switched the roles, so I use the Mac's keyboard (because Bug #18/19) and use windows as a client.

Now I cannot move the mouse over the right edge to the windows client. But if I configure windows to be on the left (virtually at least), it works, I can use the left edge to cross over to the windows client.

Dock is on the bottom.
Synergy v1.4.15

What do I need to change in order to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried your scenario and was able to replicate it. The cursor did not cross over from my Mac (10.8.5) to Windows (8.1) with Windows on the right. However, I went into "Configure Server" and changed the Windows machine to be on the left, and it worked. I then stopped the service on both machines, opened "Configure Server" again, switched Windows to the right side, stopped/started the service and it now works properly.

Maybe a glitch in the application? Try that work around and see if it fixes things for you.

Comment: Took me some time - I didn't find the time to try it, but since you had the exact same thing and found a workaround you should get credit. Thanks!